# Symfony unique year in datetime

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

is there any chance to check if the year is unique in datetime format?
I've set my unique validator from doctrine validator for unique entity, but it checks for complete date, so if i keep the same year and change the date, it will pass the validation.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * Movie
 *
 * @UniqueEntity("name", message="This movie is already in the base")
 * @UniqueEntity("releaseDate", message="Best movie from this year is already in the base")
 * @ORM\Table(name="movie")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MovieRepository")
 */
class Movie
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="release_date", type="date", unique=true)
     */
    private $releaseDate;
```

Comment: Given you're concerned with release year, why not save that on your entity as well (you can extract it from date - maybe even save it with a prepersist listener) and then set year & name as your unique entity constraints? That or you could write a custom validator that would inspect the database & ensure that the year of your date was not already taken. The former seems simpler to me.

Comment: ty and that second method worked for me, although in the end, i changed my date to simple integer since it was requested that only year is entered, and then i just added simple range checker to my releaseDate and that was it

    /**
  * @var int
     * @Assert\Range(
     * min = 1927,
     * max = 2100,
     * minMessage ="First year for the moviebase is 1927.",
     * maxMessage ="Last year for the moviebase is 2100."
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="release_date", type="integer", unique=true)
     */
    private $releaseDate;`